# How to make a Remove "X" Button on every TextBox line?

Tags: c#

Via a button, I transfer an article line by line to a shop (textBox). Everything is going well so far. Now I try to create a remove button for each line, so that erroneous entries can be deleted easily and quickly. The button appears only on the first line and I can delete the current line so not yet.

Is there a way to generate that easely? Thanks

```
float Nummer   = 0;
float Zeile    = 0;        
float SubTotal = 0;
float MwSt     = 0;
float Total    = 0;

private void btnShop1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)                                                                                                                
{
    tabControlShop1.SelectedTab = tabWarenkorbShop;

    Nummer = Nummer + 1;            

    var btn = new Button();
    btn.Size = new Size(18, 18);            
    btn.Text = "X";
    btn.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    btn.BackColor = Color.Red;
    //btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
    txtWarenkorbShop.Controls.Add(btn);

    txtWarenkorbShop.AppendText($"{Nummer}\t\tHamburger_1\t{txtPreis1.Text}\n");            
    Zeile += float.Parse(txtPreis1.Text);

    Total    = Zeile;            
    MwSt     = Total / 100 * 7;
    SubTotal = Zeile - MwSt;            
    subtotal();            
    total();   
}
```

Comment: is this winforms or webforms?

Comment: Your code looks easy for me. What's the actual issue?

Answer (score 0):

falls du Webforms verwendest, kann ich dir nicht helfen, bei Winforms müsstest du die Höhe einer Zeile bekommen und dann mit `for(int i = 0; i < txtWarenkorbShop.Lines.Count; i++)` für jede Zeile mit `lineHeight * i` an der Y Position und X die jeweilige, vor oder hinter der Textbox. Dann müssest du einfach den Text "X" hinzufügen und die Größe anpassen.

---

Hello, if you're using webforms, I can not help you, with winforms you'd have to get the height of a line and then `for (int i = 0; i <txtWarenkorbShop.Lines.Count; i ++)` for each line with `lineHeight * i` at the Y position and X the respective one, in front of or behind the text box. Then you just have to add the text "X" and adjust the size.

Kind regards

Comment: I use winforms, sorry. VS2010 C#

Comment: `@ VerbxteneSkillz` Thanks for the answer, when pressing the btnShop1 I get over `Zeile += float.Parse (txtPreis1.Text);` each time a new line. So far that works. Now, however, the new created button `btn` with which I want to delete the respective line appears only on the first click. Furthermore, I still do not know how the line remove is done right. All my attempts have failed so far.

Comment: folks, please write in English only. Other people may wish to read this and get help from it in the future, and the expectation on this site is that they only need to know English in order to do that. I understand that the German in the question is accompanied by a translation, but one of the comments is not. Nonetheless, even the German in the question is unnecessary and should be removed. Thankyou.

Comment: We will respect that in the future.

Comment: Im sorry but I cant help you :/

Comment: No problem, thanks anyway. But maybe they know how to tell the `btn` that he at least deletes the current line when I click on it?

Comment: Which variable does represent the line?

Comment: `txtWarenkorbShop.AppendText( + Nummer + "Artikel" +  txtPreis1.Text + "\n");`

Comment: For example, if I press the button `btnShop1` 5 times, 5 numbered lines will be transferred to each other in the textBox `txtWarenkorbShop`. The button `btn` is transmitted only at the first click, then no longer. And if I click on the button `btn` nothing happens. The associated line should be deleted when `btn` is clicked.

Comment: To understand, when you press the button, 5 specific lines should move to another textbox?

Comment: `@VerbxteneSkillz` no, with each click one line is written to the textBox. It should always appear a clear button to delete exactly this line again. The button itself should then disappear with the line.

Comment: I would start a private conversation but I have less reputation. Do you have Skype?

Comment: Skype is not available to me in the office. Mail ?

Comment: VerbxteneSkillz@gmail.com